# Any Glove For Hyperhidrosis While On The Computer?

Tags: clothing

I have hyperhidrosis which is a skin condition which makes you sweat excessively. So my palms are always dripping wet so whenever I'm on the laptop, my mouse gets soaked and I don't like that. I have tried using gloves but the sweat always leaks out. The only gloves that work are doctor gloves. Is there any glove out there that will help?

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever tried these type of cotton gloves?:

[image: Gloves]

I have no idea what it must be like to suffer from hyperhidrosis, but I can vouch for these gloves in that it is possible to type and use a mouse whilst wearing them. I also assume that, being cotton, they will "wick" the moisture pretty effectively.

They are incredibly cheap to buy, this picture is from Amazon UK and they are less than £2 per pair.

Answer (score 0):

What about using clinical strength antiperspirant as "hand lotion"? That may suppress the excessive perspiration to the point gloves wouldn't be necessary. Clinical strength antiperspirants are available over the counter. Your health care provider might be able to order a prescription product.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes see people putting a really small terry towel between their hand and the mouse. Maybe that would work better than a glove. They are cheap, easy to replace, absorb better than any gloves.