# Any quick wins for hyperhidrosis?

Tags: personal-care, health

I suffer from hyperhidrosis (not excessive), and one of the symptoms is clammy palms. No amount of handwashing will help, within 10 minutes my hands feel clammy again. When I hold my computer mouse, I leave a damp residue when I take my hand off.

Does anyone have a quick-win for preventing/reducing sweaty/clammy palms?

Comment: Lifehacks is not the place for health issues. Please refer to your local healthcare provider. Seeing a trained professional who can examine you in person is far more sensible than getting witchdoctor tips from strangers on the internet

Comment: A similar question was asked a few years ago on here, might be worth a look: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/16038/1965

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have this excess perspiration problem. My feet and palms sweat so much that it's difficult to do any sort of work. And while working with others, it's too embarrassing when we share things like pen or helping them with their things, as we leave some sweat on those things. Even shaking hands is too embarrassing.

Here are 2 ways:

1. [Antiperspirant lotions](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=antiperspirant+lotion&ref=nb_sb_noss_1)
2. [Cotton gloves](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=cotton+gloves&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) (doesn't reduce sweat, but you won't have irritation while doing things)

I use antiperspirant lotions, these reduce sweat but some may be allergic to these lotions. These lotions work but sometimes, I sweat a lot even after applying them. Some people may find these allergic, so choose the one which fits you the best.

When I was in my school, I used to wear cotton gloves while writing and using computer as I sweated way too much than now in school and even holding a pen was irritating (I think you understand what I mean).
So keep a pair of gloves in your pocket, use them when you feel you're about to sweat.